# find /var/log/ -type f -name *.log doesn't return list of log files

Tags: find

Instead, it returns the following error:

```
find: paths must precede expression: file1.log
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -
```

Is there something wrong with the command syntax?

(encountered this problem upon trying the accepted answer of this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657232/how-can-i-calculate-an-md5-checksum-of-a-directory))

Comment: '*' is expanded by shell before it is given to find command, see https://www.mpi-sb.mpg.de/departments/rg1/teaching/unixffb-ss98/quoting-guide.html Thus quote it.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it by enclosing the pattern in single quotations.

Comment: @silvernightstar While you should generally wait a while before accepting an answer (to allow for people from other time zones to offer answers), do consider upvoting and accepting Jiri Xhichtkniha's answer if you feel the question has been answered to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*` is expanded by shell before it is given to find command, see [A Guide to Unix Shell Quoting](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/rg1/teaching/unixffb-ss98/quoting-guide.html). Thus it has to be quoted; use `'*'` instead.